# How do I create a html text editor that does all the syntax highliting?

Tags: html, iframe, text-editor

I am looking to create a website that compiles the HTML code that you write it in a text editor. 
Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>HTML editor</title></head>
<body>
<textarea id="textarea">
</textarea>
<iframe id="frame" srcdoc="This is where the code is interpreted. ">
</iframe>
<button  onclick="run();"></button>
<script>
function run() {
    var x = document.getElementById("textarea").value;
    var y = document.getElementById("frame");
    y.srcdoc = x;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Write now, I have successfully created something that compiles html code. But I want to do the syntax highliting. How do I highlight the text?

Comment: i'd suggest using a library like [prism.js](https://prismjs.com/)

Comment: Can somebody show me how to use prism.js

Comment: I've added an asnwer, upvote/mark it as answer if helps.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the required `CSS` and `JS` for `Prism.js`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    ...
    <link href="https://myCDN.com/prism@v1.x/themes/prism.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    ...
    <script src="https://myCDN.com/prism@v1.x/components/prism-core.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://myCDN.com/prism@v1.x/plugins/autoloader/prism-autoloader.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Then add below `HTML` element

```
<pre><code class="language-css">p { color: red }</code></pre>
```

whatever code you write in this element will have syntax highlighting. `class="language-css"` determines the language for hightlighting, you can change as per your requirement. You can find all supported languages [here](https://prismjs.com/#supported-languages).

**Note:** this is a basic example you can start from here and find more info at [prism.js usage](https://prismjs.com/#basic-usage)